# How to trim a string for integer part only

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which can have values like `"45"`, `"45.00"`, `"45.0"`, `"45.000"`, `"45.23"` etc. For all these I want to save `"45"` if it's all `0` in decimal part, otherwise it would be `"45.23"`.

How can I do it? Should I use a regex expression for this?

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Either use Regex, or parse floats and later round them.

Comment: Andry: can you elaborate? or provide me the regex

Comment: Did you take a look of the class DecimalFormat?

Comment: @Dimitri: no idea of it, how it will solve my purpose

Comment: DecimalFormat is a class in Java that let you format Numbers. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use regex, try this

```
    s = s.replaceAll("(.?)(\\.0+)?", "$1");
```

Comment: will it do 45.34 to 45.34 only and 45.0 to 45?

Comment: i finally got your point, fixed, now 45.34 -> 45.34;  45.0 -> 45

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the string on a decimal point and take the first element:

```
java.util.Arrays.toString(testString.split("\\.")
```

Comment: That dot `.` needs to be escaped like `testString.split("\\.")`. `split()` works on RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize using StringTokenizer with . as delimitter

If the second token is zero, then ignore the second token, else consider the second token

Sample Code

```
StringTokenizer st = StringTokenizer(s,".");
int count = 0;
while(st.hasTokens)
{
 if (count==1)
 {
   // Read the token and compare it to zero and modify the original string s and your further processing
 }
 else{
    st.nextToken();
    count++;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
s.replaceAll("\\.0+", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after searching a little bit, I think I have found what you are looking for. No need for Regex to do it. There is a specialized class in Java for decimal formatting called [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and advise you to take a look about how to format numbers in java in this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html). Here is an example :

```
    public class NumberFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        System.out.println(myFormatter.format(45));
        System.out.println(myFormatter.format(45.000));
        System.out.println(myFormatter.format(45.23));
        System.out.println(myFormatter.format(45.258));

    }
}
```

produces the output :

```
  45
  45
  45,23
  45,26
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your string is separated by `,`, or `,`.

If you want a list of doubles, you can use:

```
List<Double> lst = new ArrayList<Double>();
for(String s : yourString.split(",\\s?")) {
    try {
        Double double = Double.valueOf(s);
        lst.add(double);
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you want a list of numbers you can use:

```
List<Number> lst = new ArrayList<Number>();
for(String s : yourString.split(",\\s?")) {
    try {
        Double double = Double.valueOf(s);
        if(double == (int)double) {
            lst.add(double);
        } else {
            lst.add((Integer)double.intValue());
        }
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```